# How to refresh Cookies for a Website in Python3X with FireFox Browser?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, session-cookies, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm currently creating a scraper that have to rely on client-side cookies being scraped of the webbrowser to then be included in a python request. It looks like this -->

```py
cj = browser_cookie3.firefox(domain_name='marketchameleon')

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Host': 'marketchameleon.com',
    'Origin': 'https://marketchameleon.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.2 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Referer': 'https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/IP/IV/',
    'Content-Length': '6',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'X-MobDisp': 'false',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

data = {
  'p': '3300'
}

response = requests.post('https://marketchameleon.com/ivCharts/getIV30_histChartData', headers=headers, cookies=cj, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

But for this to work continuously I'll need fresh and new cookies every now and then. Otherwise they'll be uneatable. But how do I create a part of the script that can refresh those cookies for [this](https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/IP/IV/) website?

I'm hence trying to create a part in the script that shall go into the browser, search up the website and thus automatically trigger the browser to create cookies for it. I've also understood that I get less cookies if I don't login, which means that a login has to be part of the script. This is what I've tried with everything but success.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

options = Options()
options.set_preference('detach', True)
browser.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Account/Login')

username = browser.find_element('name', 'UserName')
password = browser.find_element('name','Password')

username.send_keys("Username")
password.send_keys("Password")
button = browser.find_element('id', "RememberMe")
button.click()
submit = browser.find_element('id', "not_signed_inxj4e2fbtd171")
submit.click()

browser.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/IP/IV/')
time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

It sure does the job in the sense that I get into the right website, but cookies doesn't seem to be stored when using a remote-controlled browser.

(P.S. I've also discovered that it's important to use the Firefox browser since other browsers doesn't give me all the cookies using my script above.)
Please let me know if you guys have any ideas on how I could accomplish this little quest! Every form of advise is welcomed!

~ A Felow Scraper